# video.js black stroke/border removal

Tags: html5-video, video.js

We've successfully implemented video.js on http://www.hetlandgoed.be/realisaties/

Strange thing is a black border gets added. We can strip away the top and bottom ones, but not the left and right ones.

We're new to this, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI: When I visited the page, there were borders all around (Firefox 23.0.1, on Windows 7).

Comment: How were you able to remove top and bottom ones?

Answer (score 1):

The [video itself](http://www.hetlandgoed.be/video/realisaties-het-landgoed.mp4) has blank lines at the left and right edges. You can see that if you play it in Quicktime/VLC etc.

The borders top and bottom are because the video element is a slightly different aspect ratio - perhaps you did this intentionally to balance it out.

Ideally you just need a new video without the lines. Otherwise you could just hide the video edges with css:

```
.video.carousel {
  width: 934px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

#my_video_1 {
  margin-left: -3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can edit video.js. 
Search for this:

```
{wmode:"opaque",bgcolor:"#000000"}
```

and change to

```
{wmode:"opaque",bgcolor:"#FFFFFF"}
```